# Inverting a fold

Tags: haskell, fold

Suppose for a minute that we think the following is a good idea:

```
data Fold x y = Fold {start :: y, step :: x -> y -> y}

fold :: Fold x y -> [x] -> y
```

Under this scheme, functions such as `length` or `sum` can be implemented by calling `fold` with the appropriate `Fold` object as argument.

Now, suppose you want to do clever optimisation tricks. In particular, suppose you want to write

```
unFold :: ([x] -> y) -> Fold x y
```

It should be relatively easy to rule a `RULES` pragma such that `fold . unFold = id`. But the interesting question is... can we actually *implement* `unFold`?

Obviously you can use `RULES` to apply arbitrary code transformations, whether or not they preserve the original meaning of the code. But can you really write an `unFold` implementation which actually does what its type signature suggests?

Comment: have you seen http://conal.net/blog/posts/more-beautiful-fold-zipping ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, but you need to make a slight modification to `Fold` in order to pull it off.

All functions on lists can be expressed as a fold, but sometimes to accomplish this, *extra bookkeeping is needed*. Suppose we add an additional type parameter to your `Fold` type, which passes along this additional contextual information.

```
data Fold a c r = Fold { _start :: (c, r), _step :: a -> (c,r) -> (c,r) }
```

Now we can implement `fold` like so

```
fold :: Fold a c r -> [a] -> r
fold (Fold step start) = snd . foldr step start
```

Now what happens when we try to go the other way?

```
unFold :: ([a] -> r) -> Fold a c r
```

Where does the `c` come from? Functions are opaque values, so it's hard to know how to inspect a function and know which contextual information it relies on. So, let's cheat a little. We're going to have the "contextual information" be the entire list, so then when we get to the leftmost element, we can just apply the function to the original list, ignoring the prior cumulative results.

```
unFold :: ([a] -> r) -> Fold a [a] r
unFold f = Fold { _start = ([], f [])
                , _step = \a (c, _r) -> let c' = a:c in (c', f c') }
```

---

Now, sadly, this does not necessarily compose with `fold`, because it requires that `c` must be `[a]`. Let's fix that by hiding `c` with existential quantification.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data Fold a r = forall c. Fold
  { _start :: (c,r)
  , _step :: a -> (c,r) -> (c,r) }

fold :: Fold a r -> [a] -> r
fold (Fold start step) = snd . foldr step start

unFold :: ([a] -> r) -> Fold a r
unFold f = Fold start step where
  start = ([], f [])
  step a (c, _r) = let c' = a:c in (c', f c')
```

Now, it should always be true that `fold . unFold = id`. And, given a relaxed notion of equality for the `Fold` data type, you could also say that `unFold . fold = id`. You can even provide a smart constructor that acts like the old `Fold` constructor:

```
makeFold :: r -> (a -> r -> r) -> Fold a r
makeFold start step = Fold start' step' where
  start' = ((), start)
  step' a ((), r) = ((), step a r)
```

Answer (score 12):

No, it's not possible. Proof: let

```
f :: [()] -> Bool
f[] = False
f[()] = False
f _ = True
```

First we must, for `f' = unFold f`, have `start f' = False`, because when folding over the empty list we directly get the start value. Then we must require `step f' () False = False` to achieve `fold f' [()] = False`. But when now evaluating `fold f' [(),()]`, we would again only get a call `step f' () False`, which we had to define as `False`, leading to `fold f' [(),()] ≡ False`, whereas `f[(),()] ≡ True`. So there exists no `unFold f` that fulfills `fold $ unFold f ≡ f`.                                                                                                                                              □

Answer (score 6):

tl;dr:

### Conclusion 1: you can't

What you asked for originally isn't possible, at least not by any version of what you wanted I can come up with. (See below.)
If change your data type to allow me to store intermediate calculations, I think I'll be fine, but even then,
the function `unFold` would be rather inefficient, which seems to run counter to your clever optimisation tricks agenda!

### Conclusion 2: I don't think it achieves what you want, even if you work around it by changing the types

Any optimisation of the list algorithm would be subject to the problem that you've calculated the step function using the original unoptimised function, and quite probably in a complicated way.

Since there's no equality on functions, optimising step to something efficient isn't possible. I think you need a human to do `unFold`, not a compiler.

Anyway, back to the original question:

### Could fold . unFold = id ?

No. Suppose we have

```
isSingleton :: [a] -> Bool
isSingleton [x] = True
isSingleton _ = False
```

then if we had `unFold :: ([x] -> y) -> Fold x y` then if `foldSingleton` was the same as `unFold isSingleton` would need to have

```
foldSingleton = Fold {start = False , step = ???}
```

Where step takes an element of the list and updates the result.
Now `isSingleton "a" == True`, we need

```
step False = True
```

and because `isSingleton "ab" == False`, we need

```
step True = False
```

so `step = not` would do so far, but also `isSingleton "abc" == False` so we also need

```
step False = False
```

Since there are functions `([x] -> y)` that cannot be represented by a value of type `Fold x y`, there cannot exist a function `unFold :: ([x] -> y) -> Fold x y` such that `fold . unFold = id`, because `id` is a total function.

---

Edit:

It turns out you're not convinced by this, because you only expected `unFold` to work on functions that had a representation as a fold, so maybe you meant `unFold.fold = id`.

### Could unFold . fold = id ?

No.
Even if you just want `unFold` to work on functions `([x] -> y)` that can be obtained using `fold :: Fold x y -> ([x] -> y)`, I don't think it's possible. Let's address the question by assuming now we have defined

```
combine :: X -> Y -> Y
initial :: Y

folded :: [X] -> Y
folded = fold $ Fold initial combine
```

Recovering the value `initial` is trivial: `initial = folded []`. 
Recovery of the original `combine` is not, because there's no way to go from a function that gives you some values of `Y` to one which combines arbitrary values of `Y`.

For an example, if we had `X = Y = Int` and I defined

```
    combine x y | y < 0 = -10
                | otherwise = y + 1
    initial = 0
```

then since `combine` just adds one to `y` every time you use it on positive `y`, and the initial value is 0, `folded` is indistinguishable from `length` in terms of its output. Notice that since `folded xs` is never negative, it's also impossible to define a function `unFold :: ([x] -> y) -> Fold x y` that ever recovers our `combine` function. This boils down to the fact that `fold` is not injective; it carries different values of type `Fold x y` to the same value of type `[x] -> y`.

Thus I've proved two things: if `unFold :: ([x] -> y) -> Fold x y` then both `fold.unFold /= id` and now also `unFold.fold /= id`

I bet you're not convinced by this either, because you don't really care whether you got `Fold 0 (\_ y -> y+1)` or `Fold 0 combine` back from `unFold folded`, seeing as they have the same value when refolded! Let's narrow the goalposts one more time. Perhaps you want `unFold` to work whenever the function is obtainable via `fold`, and you're happy for it not to give you inconsistent answers as long as when you fold the result again, you get the same function. I can summarise that with this next question:

### Could fold . unFold . fold = fold ?

i.e. Could you define `unFold` so that `fold.unFold` is the identity on the set of functions obtainable via `fold`?

I'm really convinced this isn't possible, because it's not a tractible problem to calculate the `step` function without retaining extra information about intermediate values on sublists.

Suppose we had

```
unFold f = Fold {start = f [], step = recoverstep f}
```

we need

```
recoverstep f x1 initial == f [x1]
```

so if there's an Eq instance for x (ring the alarm bells!), then recoverstep must have the same effect as

```
recoverstep f x1 y | y == initial = f [x1]
```

also we need

```
recoverstep f x2 (f [x1]) == f [x1,x2]
```

so if there's an Eq instance for x, then recoverstep must have the same effect as

```
recoverstep f x2 y | y == (f [x1]) = f [x1,x2]
```

but there's a massive problem here: the variable `x1` is free in the right hand side of this equation.
This means that logically, we can't tell what value the step function should have on an x unless we already 
know what values it has been used on. We would need to store the values of `f [x1]`, `f [x1,x2]` etc in the Fold 
data type to make it work, and this is the clincher as to why we can't define `unFold`. If you change the data type Fold
to allow us to store information about intermediate lists, I can see it would work, but as it stands it's impossible 
to recover the context.

Comment: "Since there are functions that cannot be represented by a value of type `Fold x y`, there cannot exist a function `unFold`." Or rather, there cannot exist a _total_ function. My question is whether you can write an `unFold` that works for every possible `Fold`, not necessarily every possible general list function.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid This isn't really a fair criticism since you stated `fold . unFold = id`, and `id` is total (I edited my answer to explain so). Did you mean `unFold.fold = id`?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I've edited now to try to prove it's not possible for all the reasonable interpretations I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12958624/98117), but using a slightly different approach. Instead of pairing the accumulator with partial results which will be thrown away at the end, we add a "post-processing" function which will convert from the accumulator type to the final result.

The same "cheat" for `unFold` just does all the work in the post-processing step:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Fold a r = forall c. Fold
  { _start  :: c
  , _step   :: a -> c -> c
  , _result :: c -> r }

fold :: Fold a r -> [a] -> r
fold (Fold start step result) = result . foldr step start

unFold :: ([a] -> r) -> Fold a r
unFold f = Fold [] (:) f

makeFold :: r -> (a -> r -> r) -> Fold a r
makeFold start step = Fold start step id
```

Comment: Your inclusion of `f` on the right hand side of `unFold` amused me, so I've got the following joke suggestion: I could simplify your solution somewhat by further redefining the data structure Fold, in which you have included two fields I think complicate the solution somewhat and necessitate existential types. Why not define `unFold f = Fold f` and `fold (Fold f) = f`. It would work more efficiently!

Comment: @AndrewC: Haha! I guess it just illustrates what most of the answers here are already saying. You can't do it without cheating - badly.

Comment: More seriously, despite the unavoidable existential type, this is a very elegant bit of code that made me smile, so +1.